# Problem running JDK on Manjaro Linux for React Native

Tags: java, react-native, archlinux, manjaro

The [React Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) says,

> React Native requires version 8 of the Java SE Development Kit (JDK). You may download and install OpenJDK from AdoptOpenJDK or your system packager. You may also Download and install Oracle JDK 8 if desired.

The last command I remember trying to install JDK is

```
sudo pacman -S jdk8-openjdk
```

And when I run

```
npx react-native run-android
```

on the project directory, I get this error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

I'm on Manjaro Linux.

Comment: Can you check if you have a directory in `/usr/lib/jvm`  with the name `jdk1.8.0`

Comment: No, there isn't. Should there be?

Comment: you should have a directory with a name that's contains `jdk1.8.0`, and you need to setup your `JAVA_HOME` variable to point to this directory

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. If you open the android project in android studios, then build it there. then go back to the terminal and run `npx react-native start` it works

However, I'm still having the same issue of trying to get `npx react-native run-android` to work.

Comment: How do I build from Android Studios?